# Help in writing linear equations based on conditionality in GAMS (9 variables)

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming, binary-programming

I have tried following problem, but I could not solve it. Can you please help me in this?

I have 8 *binary* variables : *a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h*

I want to define a variable (*x*) with the help of linear equations with following conditions:

- $x=0$, if $a+b+c+d+e+f+g+h\leq 1$
- $x=1$, if $a+b+c+d+e+f+g+h>1$

Further, in my problem, these variables can be more or less than 8. Thus, can you help me in finding a general set of linear equations with $n$ binary variables satisfying the following:

- $x=0$, if $a+b+c+d+e+f+g+h+\ldots\leq1$
- $x=1$, if $a+b+c+d+e+f+g+h+\ldots >1$

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can enforce the logical implication
$x = 1 \implies \sum_{j=1}^n y_j \ge 2$
by imposing linear constraint
$\sum_{j=1}^n y_j \ge 2x$.

You can enforce the logical implication
$x = 0 \implies \sum_{j=1}^n y_j \le 1$
by imposing linear constraint
$\sum_{j=1}^n y_j - 1 \le (n-1)x$.

As a check, there are two cases:

- $x=1$ yields $2 \le \sum_{j=1}^n y_j \le n$.
- $x=0$ yields $0 \le \sum_{j=1}^n y_j \le 1$.

Comment: I did not follow the second condition. Let's say if sum over all binary variables is 0, then *x* has to be greater than -1/8. But it isn't making sense to me. While I appreciate your answer, can u please explain it a bit taking few conditions, such as if sum is 0, 1 , 7 etc?

Comment: I updated the answer with the two cases just now.

Comment: Hey , it seems that your solution is not one-to-one. It is one to many. In other words, If I will keep *x=1*, then I may get the other condition satisfied. But converse is not true.

Comment: Not sure what you mean.  My formulation (imposing both linear constraints simultaneously) enforces $x=1 \iff \sum_j y_j \ge 2$. Equivalently, $x=0 \iff \sum_j y_j \le 1$.